# How to get Bootstrap 5.3.x DropDown functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor website, I've tried the bootstrap 5.3.x dropdown sample code, and it doesn't function in my site at all. I have the bootstrap css and js in my _Host.cshtml (one in the head, the other just before the body close), and I've copy/pasted their sample code directly. It doesn't work at all. In order to make the dropdown open, I had to include ids on both the drop down toggle button and on the container it would open, a `data-bs-target` on the button that pointed to the container, and change the `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` to `data-bs-toggle="collapse"`.

The following failed to function (clicking the button did nothing at all):

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but changing it to this actually worked:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" id="thing1" data-bs-target="thing2">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="thing2" aria-labelledby="thing1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So, great - it opens and closes, but this also means that their sample for auto-close doesn't function for me either. I tried all 4 samples for auto-close, and none of them did a thing.

I'm hoping someone out there has run into, and sorted out, this same issue.

For reference: my _Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace MyWebsite.App.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <base href="~/" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

        @* Bootstrap 5 *@
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />

        @* Font-Awesome 6 *@
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome/css/brands.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome/css/sharp-light.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome/css/sharp-regular.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/font-awesome/css/sharp-solid.min.css" />

        <link href="~/css/telerik/blazor/5.0.1/kendo-theme-bootstrap/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bzstyle.css?version=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString()" />

        <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />

        <div id="blazor-error-ui">
            <environment include="Load,UAT,Production">
                An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
            </environment>
            <environment include="Development,LocalTest,Test,TestAutomation">
                An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
            </environment>
            <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
            <a class="dismiss"></a>
        </div>


        <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        @* Popper JS - for drop downs, popovers, etc.. *@
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/popper/popper.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://blazor.cdn.telerik.com/blazor/5.0.1/telerik-blazor.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            if (!window.TelerikBlazor) { // the Telerik object is not present
                var newScript = document.createElement("script");
                newScript.setAttribute("src", "_content/Telerik.UI.for.Blazor/js/telerik-blazor.js"); // path to static assets from the Telerik package
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 + Blazor does have some quirks, like Carousel auto play. However, the Dropdowns have have always worked without any problems.  You may want to try using the [Bootstrap bundle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/#cdn-via-jsdelivr) as opposed to loading Popper as a separate file.

Comment: What version of Popper?

Comment: @Yogi - You're a life saver! Using the bundle immediately allowed the default goodies from BS5.x to start working as advertised! Thank you so much! Can you put that into an answer, so I can accept it can give you credit?